# Chrome 80 can resolve a non configured local hostname to ::1

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have a local web service listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
When accessing from chrome, I used abc.localhost:8080/someWebPage, and chrome is able to resolve the hostname abc.localhost to ::1 while other browsers don't.

here is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       subdomain1.localhost
```

I disabled "Preload pages for faster browsing and searching" option in Privacy and security section in Chrome settings.

I cleared host cache from chrome://net-internals/#dns and also executed the ipconfig /flushdns command

Here is a snippet from chrome netlog, that shows abc.localhost is resolved to ::1 :

```
abc.localhost:8080
Start Time: 2020-03-18 12:52:49.027

t=2574 [st=   0] +SOCKET_ALIVE  [dt=1897+]
                  --> source_dependency = 29267 (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_JOB)
t=2574 [st=   0]   +TCP_CONNECT  [dt=1]
                    --> address_list = ["[::1]:8080","127.0.0.1:8080"]
                    --> canonical_name = ""
t=2574 [st=   0]      TCP_CONNECT_ATTEMPT  [dt=1]
                      --> address = "[::1]:8080"
t=2575 [st=   1]   -TCP_CONNECT
                    --> source_address = "[::1]:64756"
t=2575 [st=   1]   +SOCKET_IN_USE  [dt=56]
```

Could anyone explain how google chrome browser is able to resolve a hostname not configured in the hosts file, and how to disable this behavior.
I am using chrome version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) and my os is windows 10

**Updates**
I found an answer here [Chrome ignoring hosts file for subdomains of localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39666979/10330261) which points to the chromium bug tracker  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489973
Another related issue
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455825

Chrome does not rely on hosts file anymore, it will force localhost and *.localhost hostnames to be always resolved to loopback address as stated in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome overrides the localhost domain, will completely ignore the hosts file and dns lookup entirely for security reasons.

Comment: Can you provide documentation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did not find any documentation that mentions this, and also could this behavior be disabled?

Comment: @Ramhound refer to this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489973

Comment: @Wafa - Your question should contain that information instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and went to "settings" -> "privacy and security" -> "safe browsing" There I set it from "standard protection" to "no protection". Then addresses in my /etc/host file worked including ones like `127.0.0.1  some.domain.org`